# How to Ends the AnimatorSet by using nineoldandroid?

Tags: android, nineoldandroids

I am using nineoldandroid for Animation.

My codes as follow:

```
Button mTarget;
Animator mTargetAnim;
AnimatorSet mTargetScaleAnimSet;

private void createAnimation() {
    if (mTargetAnim == null) {
        ObjectAnimator yAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mTarget, "y",
                mTarget.getY(), mTarget.getY() + 500).setDuration(3500);
        yAnim.setRepeatCount(0);
        yAnim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
        yAnim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(2f));
        yAnim.addListener(this);

        ObjectAnimator xAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mTarget, "x",
                mTarget.getX(), mTarget.getX() + 500).setDuration(3500);
        xAnim.setStartDelay(0);
        xAnim.setRepeatCount(0);
        xAnim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
        xAnim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(2f));
        // the first AnimatorSet
        AnimatorSet xyAnimSet = new AnimatorSet();
        xyAnimSet.playTogether(yAnim, xAnim);

        mTargetScaleAnimSet = new AnimatorSet();
        ObjectAnimator scaleXAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mTarget,
                "scaleX", 1f, 0f, 0.2f, 0f);
        ObjectAnimator scaleYAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mTarget,
                "scaleY", 1f, 0f, 0.2f, 0f);
        mTargetScaleAnimSet.playTogether(scaleXAnim,
                scaleYAnim);
        mTargetScaleAnimSet.setDuration(3000);
        mTargetScaleAnimSet.addListener(this);


        mTargetAnim = new AnimatorSet();
        ((AnimatorSet) mTargetAnim).playSequentially(xyAnimSet, mTargetScaleAnimSet);

        mTargetAnim.addListener(this);
    }
}
```

Before the beginning of the second Animator(mTargetScaleAnimSet), I call the end() method to end the entire AnimatorSet. However, I found the end() method can not end all of child Animators in the AnimatorSet.

**Q: How to all of child Animators playing Sequentially?**

Answer (score 0):

After some brainstorming, I found a solution as follow：

**Firstly:**

```
mScaleAnimSet.setStartDelay(3500);
```

**Then:**

```
mTargetAnimSet.playSequentially(mTransAnimSet, mScaleAnimSet);
```

change to:

```
mTargetAnimSet.playTogether(mTransAnimSet, mScaleAnimSet );
```

**I think the key is that if the Animation does not start, you can not end it.**